# Date to Day Converter

Tags: php, date, converters

I have seen other questions asked about how to parse a date to the day of the week with the date hard coded into the code, but how would I go about doing the same from a form that posts to itself? Basically there are two dropdown (one for month and one for day) and a field to enter a year. I can't figure out how to take these three fields and put it into a single $date and then use`echo date('l', strtotime($date));` to display it.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['month'])){
        $_SESSION['month']= 01;
}
$month = $_SESSION['month'];
if(isset($_POST['month'])){
        $month = $_POST['month'];
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['day'])){
        $_SESSION['day']= 01;
}
$day = $_SESSION['day'];
if(isset($_POST['day'])){
        $day = $_POST['day'];
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['year'])){
        $_SESSION['year']= 0000;
}
$year = $_SESSION['year'];
if(isset($_POST['year'])){
        $year = $_POST['year'];
}

if(!isset($_SESION['date'])){
        $_SESSION['date'] = 'month'.'/'.'day'.'/'.'year';
}
$date = $_SESSION['date'];
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
        $date= $_POST['date'];
}
if(!isset($_SESION['date'])){
    $_SESSION['date'] = $month.$day.$year;
}
$date = $_SESSION['date'];
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
        $date= $_POST['date'];
}
echo date('l', strtotime($date));
session_destroy();
?>
```

My form is here:

```
<body>
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>    method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Date to Day Converter</legend>
Month:<br>
<select name="month">
<option value=01>January</option>
<option value=02>February</option>
<option value=03>March</option>
<option value=04>April</option>
<option value=05>May</option>
<option value=06>June</option>
<option value=07>July</option>
<option value=08>August</option>
<option value=09>September</option>
<option value=10>October</option>
<option value=11>November</option>
<option value=12>December</option>
</select>
<br>
Day:<br>
<select name="day">
<option value=01>01</option>
<option value=02>02</option>
<option value=03>03</option>
<option value=04>04</option>
<option value=05>05</option>
<option value=06>06</option>
<option value=07>07</option>
<option value=08>08</option>
<option value=09>09</option>
<option value=10>10</option>
<option value=11>11</option>
<option value=12>12</option>
<option value=13>13</option>
<option value=14>14</option>
<option value=15>15</option>
<option value=16>16</option>
<option value=17>17</option>
<option value=18>18</option>
<option value=19>19</option>
<option value=20>20</option>
<option value=21>21</option>
<option value=22>22</option>
<option value=23>23</option>
<option value=24>24</option>
<option value=25>25</option>
<option value=26>26</option>
<option value=27>27</option>
<option value=28>28</option>
<option value=29>29</option>
<option value=30>30</option>
<option value=31>31</option>
</select>
<br>
Year:<br>
<input type="text" name"year">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the code you've posted give you?

Comment: for any date I enter, it tells me Wednesday

Comment: If you echo `$date` is it correct?

Comment: no, no matter what date I enter into the form, when it goes through the php portion of the code, the $date echoed is always wednesday

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. If you echo `$date`, not `date`, is it the date that you are submitting?

Comment: By doing that, I get 04020.  I am submitting month, day, year.  Month and day are an input type="select" and year is a text input.

Comment: So I think your `year` isn't processing correctly (or `date`). Can you post your form?

Comment: Ya, I just edited the initial code to post the form as well...sorry about the length.

Comment: You've misspelled `SESSION` as `SESION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a bug in your HTML. You are missing an `=` in the following line of code:

```
<input type="text" name"year">
```

This means your year will never be submitted and default to 0;

Secondly, have a look at this part of your code:

```
if(!isset($_SESION['date'])){
        $_SESSION['date'] = 'month'.'/'.'day'.'/'.'year';
}
$date = $_SESSION['date'];
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
        $date= $_POST['date'];
}
if(!isset($_SESION['date'])){
    $_SESSION['date'] = $month.$day.$year;
}
$date = $_SESSION['date'];
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
        $date= $_POST['date'];
}
```

In your first `if` you set the date in session to 'month/day/year'. You do not post any 'date' variable, so the second `if` won't be executed. The third `if` won't be executed either, since you just set the `date` variable in your session. That fourth `if` is just a copy of the second one, and still won't be executed for the same reason.

In the end your $date wil contain 'month/day/year', which php can't parse, so it defaults to the unix epoch, which happens to be on a Wednesday.

You should change the entire block of code I quoted above to something like this:

```
$date = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;
$_SESSION['date'] = $date;
```

Now your script should work as expected

Comment: Ya I stepped away from the code and came back to it and realized that I made that I did that if statement for the date more than once.  I fixed it and now I just need to correct incorrect days for february and account for leap years.  Thanks for the help, sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes